# Name for a Specific Type of Non-Symmetric Bilinear Form

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, quadratic-forms

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, with some choice of basis $\{e_i\}_{i \in I}$. With respect to an idempotent bijection $B:I \to I$, define a bilinear form by
$$
g = \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_{i} e^i \otimes e^{B(j)},
$$
where $\{e^i\}_{i \in I}$ is the dual basis of $V^*$. Moreover, assume that $\lambda_i \neq \lambda_{I(i)}$, implying that $g$ is not a symmetric form. I would like to know if such a $g$ has a name, and if anyone has previously considered such objects.

Comment: Do you mean $B(i)$ rather than $I(j)$ in the superscript?  And is $I=\lbrace 1, \dots, N \rbrace$?

Comment: . . . and yes $I=\{1,\ldots, N\}$.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the following link helpful:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_permutation_matrix